# How are defined base address on linux?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, assembly

I need help to understand what is the value of the base adress of a program in elf linux. It could help me understand what is the exact value of the symbol $ somewhere in the code. For example bios load the mbr at 0x7c00. So to find a value we must add her offset to the base adress. How can I do that on linux?

Comment: It's chosen by the linker, or, in the case of ASLR, randomly at runtime.  In almost all cases you should write your code in such a way that you don't need to know it.

Comment: Do you know any documentation that could help me understand how the base adress is defined? I know I can just let the complier but I don't want to be ignorant.

Comment: You can use `readelf -a` on a non-PIE executable to see the segment load addresses.  Relevant search term: "linker relocations" for how the linker fills in address references at link time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However even by searching about linker relocations, I still can't predict the absolute adress of a byte.

Comment: Plus, when I put the virtual address of the data segment in a jmp instruction it's giving me some segmentation errors.

Comment: That's right, you can't easily predict an absolute address, and what I'm saying is that you should not try.  It's not ignorance, just good encapsulation.

Comment: You can write a custom linker script, or look at `ld`'s default linker script (or the practical effects, e.g. where each section starts), if you really want to know about absolute addresses.  From the section starts, you can count bytes if you really want to (and know how each insn assembles), but that's painful.  Usually just write code, assemble+link it, and see what ends up where.  Move code/data around to reduce the amount of padding needed to get the alignment you want after you see how your first attempt goes.

Comment: Re: jumping to `.data` - yes, of course, that's by design: `.data` is RW without exec for security reasons, with normal linker options.